# error CS0103 in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

Hello when I compile a ASP.NET C# project using file Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe  I am getting an error as "ERROR CS0103: The name (forms name) cannot be found in the current context"

This error is displayed individually for every where I use ASP.NET forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add designer file to your code file.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

An attempt was made to use a name that does not exist in the class, namespace, or scope. Check the spelling of the name and check your using statements and assembly references to make sure that the name you are trying to use is available. **One common mistake is to declare a variable within a loop or a try block and then attempt to access it from an enclosing code block or another code block**.

Answer (score 0):

Use compile.bat file to compile all the files and make sure that designer files are included. This error occurs only when designer file is not present in the context.