# Unity3D v5.4 - GUILayout does not exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make game menu. For this, I will need `GUIlayout` and its methods. However, looks like `Unity` cannot find `GUIlayout` object, displaying this error:

> Assets/scripts/GameManager.cs(38,25): error CS0103: The name `GUIlayout' does not exist in the current context

My Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public bool isMenuActive{get;set;}

void Awake () {
    isMenuActive = true;
}

void OnGUI(){
    const int Width = 300;
    const int Height = 200;
    if (isMenuActive){
        Rect windowRect = new Rect((Screen.width - Width) / 2 ,(Screen.height - Height) / 2, Width , Height);
        GUIlayout.window(0,windowRect,MainMenu,"Main menu");
    }
}

private void MainMenu(){
    // Debug.Log("menu is displayed");
}

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error CS0103 in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119207/error-cs0103-in-asp-net)

Comment: It should be "GUILayout", and not "GUIlayout". (Case Sensitive) You shouldn't be using OnGUI in Unity 5.4. The support for it will soon be dropped. Use UnityUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from the line of code:

```
GUILayout.Window(0, windowRect, MainMenu, "Main menu");
```

**1**.It's `GUILayout` not `GUIlayout`. The '**L**' is capitalized.

**2**.The static function of `GUILayout` used is `Window` not `window`. The-same capitalization problem from problem #1.

**3**.The third parameter of the `Window` function requires a function with an int parameter to be passed into it. You have to parameterize your `MainMenu` function with an `int`.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool isMenuActive { get; set; }

    void Awake()
    {
        isMenuActive = true;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        const int Width = 300;
        const int Height = 200;
        if (isMenuActive)
        {
            Rect windowRect = new Rect((Screen.width - Width) / 2, (Screen.height - Height) / 2, Width, Height);
            GUILayout.Window(0, windowRect, MainMenu, "Main menu");
        }
    }

    private void MainMenu(int windowID)
    {
        // Debug.Log("menu is displayed");
    }
}
```

Finally, you shouldn't be using [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html). You should be using the [new](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) Unity UI. [Here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui)'s a tutorial for that.

Comment: Looks like i followed an old Unity tutorial. Thanks a lot for your help!