# Fake error in VS 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Whenever I start a build in my website, the second the build starts, I get tons of fake errors about page controls being unrecognized (see image).
After the build succeeds, the error still appear in the output pane.
They only disappear if I **double click** them and **open the web page** in which they exist.ution

This is not a duplicate for "error CS0103 in ASP.NET" post.
There is no solution there, and the suggestions given are not relevant to this post.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error CS0103 in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119207/error-cs0103-in-asp-net)

Comment: This is not a duplicate for "error CS0103 in ASP.NET" post.
There is no solution there, and the suggestions given are not relevant to this post.

Comment: No easy fix that I know of. "Usually" the "real" error is toward the _bottom_ of the pile in the Errors window. If this is a `solution` (of `projects`), other tips (though this will be evident if the real error does surface at the "end of the pile"): versioning of referenced assemblies (differing assembly versions in projects), build order, etc. Hth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have not a 100% solution, I have found if you close the many windows you might have opened in VS (windows of other aspx pages that you've worked on before and left opened), it will get rid of a majority of these fake errors.

Then for the rest, just double click to open up one of these fake error for a particular aspx page, then after a few seconds, all the fake errors relating to that page will disappear (guessing some partial building/intellisensing happens and clears the kink).

Hope that helps a bit.